# Adding extra column in a Data Frame with the use of existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I have the following data frame:

```
                                  Movie     Budget  Worldwide Gross  Year
0                                  2012  200000000        791217826  2009
1                               Aladdin  183000000       1050693953  2019
2                   Alice in Wonderland  200000000       1025468216  2010
3                               Aquaman  160000000       1148485886  2018
4                                Avatar  237000000       2847246203  2009
```

And with this I have to use:

```
usuario = int(input('Cual es la pelicula que desea buscar? '))
opcion1 = datos[datos["Movie"] == usuario ]
```

In order to look for a specific movie provided by the user.

I have to create a additional column called 'Percentage of profit" by doing this: (Worldwide Gross/Budget * 100)... I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
datos["porcentage de ganancia"] = datos["Worldwide Gross"] / datos["Budget"] * 100
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's your pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('2012', 200000000, 791217826, 2009), 
        ('Aladdin', 183000000, 1050693953, 2019), 
        ('Alice in Wonderland', 200000000, 1025468216, 2010), 
        ('Aquaman', 160000000, 1148485886, 2018), 
        ('Avatar', 237000000, 2847246203, 2009), 
    ], 
    columns=['Movie', 'Budget', 'Worldwide Gross', 'Year']
)

print(df)

                 Movie     Budget  Worldwide Gross  Year
0                 2012  200000000        791217826  2009
1              Aladdin  183000000       1050693953  2019
2  Alice in Wonderland  200000000       1025468216  2010
3              Aquaman  160000000       1148485886  2018
4               Avatar  237000000       2847246203  2009
```

And this works fine

```
df["porcentage de ganancia"] = df["Worldwide Gross"] / df["Budget"] * 100
print(df) 

                 Movie     Budget  Worldwide Gross  Year  porcentage de ganancia
0                 2012  200000000        791217826  2009              395.608913
1              Aladdin  183000000       1050693953  2019              574.149701
2  Alice in Wonderland  200000000       1025468216  2010              512.734108
3              Aquaman  160000000       1148485886  2018              717.803679
4               Avatar  237000000       2847246203  2009             1201.369706
```

---

So I suspect there might be something wrong with your `dtypes`. You can check them using `df.dtypes`. If that's the problem this should do the trick:

```
df["porcentage de ganancia"] = df["Worldwide Gross"].astype(int) / df["Budget"].astype(int) * 100
```